# Hadoop cluster on Google cloud platform doesn't start

Tags: python, hadoop, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

I'm trying to create a Hadoop cluster in the Google Cloud Platform using the following resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop

After setting up the Hadoop cluster, I try to start Hadoop and get this error:

```
File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 60, in __call__
   oauth2client.tools.gflags.FLAGS.auth_local_webserver = False
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gflags'
```

I'm accessing the instance through SSH and I'm using `--noauth_local_webserver`

Comment: I didn't try yet the Google Cloud, but this seems to be an error about oauth2, so about authentication. Did you forget a scope during the oauth2 dance?

Answer (score 1):

If you visit

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/hadoop/

you will now be directed to

https://developers.google.com/hadoop/

The "bdutil" scripts that are downloadable there (see "Obtain the setup scripts") are the recommended Hadoop startup scripts from Google.